# BadRequestError: checks.state argument is missing - What changed?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, openid-connect, auth0

Tabled a development project back in November and picked it back up.
The authorization that was working is not working any longer and gives me the following error.

```
BadRequestError: checks.state argument is missing
    at /base/node_modules/express-openid-connect/middleware/auth.js:121:31
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

Originally I was running my server in development over http, but I thought maybe the issue was that my local server was not HTTP, so now I'm accessing it over HTTPs with a self signed certificate, if perhaps that is the issue.

I am using an ngrok proxy to support the callback to my development environment and have

```
OIDC_RP_URI=https://myproxy.ngrok.io
OIDC_COOKIE_DOMAIN=myproxy.ngrok.io


  auth = {
  authRequired: true, // validate<boolean>('DISABLE_SSO', Boolean(env.DISABLE_SSO), isBoolean, false),
  baseURL: validate<string>('OIDC_RP_URI', env.OIDC_RP_URI, isString),
  clientID: validate<string>('OIDC_CLIENT_ID', env.OIDC_CLIENT_ID, isString),
  issuerBaseURL: validate<string>('OIDC_OP_URI', env.OIDC_OP_URI, isString),
  routes: {
    callback: validate<string>('OIDC_REDIRECT_PATH', env.OIDC_REDIRECT_PATH, isString),
    logout: '/logout',
    postLogoutRedirect: 'https://xx/Logout'
  },
  secret: validate<string>('EXPRESS_SESSION_SECRET', env.EXPRESS_SESSION_SECRET, isString),
  session: {
    cookie: {
      domain: validate<string>('OIDC_COOKIE_DOMAIN', env.OIDC_COOKIE_DOMAIN, isString),
      httpOnly: true,
      path: '/',
      sameSite: 'None' as const, // 'Lax' as const,
      secure: true
    },
    absoluteDuration: 60 * 60 * 8,
    rollingDuration: 60 * 60
  }
```